# Writing a unit testing framework for testing SQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, frameworks

Today I had an idea of writing a unit testing framework for stored procedures in MySQL. The full idea is written on a recent post on my blog. In short it goes like this: 
I want to automate my procedure testing, I want to use a standardized way to test my procedures. Unit testing is widely documented, and there are a zillion XUnit frameworks out there, why not write one for MySQL (or any other database). 
It would be open source of course. 
What do you think? It is silly, stupid, needless or what?
Or another idea would be to write a general database framework in SQL. Hmm, I really want to discuss that with someone, collect thoughts and ideas.

Comment: A different but related scenario: I have seen cases where foreign keys were accidentally dropped and caused havoc after a month or two.  It might be a good idea to have automated tests for scenarios like this.

Comment: of, course.. you could actually unit test your entire database, setting scenarios , testing them and then rolling back the database to its previous state. Every major RDMBS has tools to do that.

Comment: It is silly, stupid, needless or what? Yes

Comment: You mean like [MyTAP](http://theory.github.com/mytap/)?

Answer (score 3):

There's already one testing framework for Sql Server - [TSQLUnit](http://tsqlunit.sourceforge.net/). Maybe you can get some useful info from it.

Comment: Thnx for the link, I will sure check it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, great idea. I've been having a fair bit of success with [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/). I've used it in a number of projects, both for [test driven database development](http://www.oscon.com/oscon2010/public/schedule/detail/14168) and to write tests for existing procedures in order to be able to effectively refactor them.

I have often been asked if there's something like it for MySQL. Maybe you've written something by now?

Answer (score 1):

There are already unit tests out there. Apart from dbUnit and sqlUnit, try:

MyTAP: https://github.com/hepabolu/mytap
datacharmer.org: http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2006/01/mysql-5-general-purpose-routine_27.html

Answer (score 0):

I tend to unit test the data access layer, it is always a pain in the ass because you have to setup a proper database with proper data.  There are data generators out there that can help (like RedGate's Data Generator) make the setup process simpler.

My thinking behind just testing the DAL, is that you are essentially testing the stored procedures themselves with the added .Net DB code which I don't think we need to worry about unit testing.  This way you can leverage all the tools and processes you already have for unit testing.  It seems like a lot of effort to develop a separate framework for something that can (IMHO) be performed equally well with existing tools.

I have an open mind though.  If there are benefits I am overlooking please do tell me.

Cheers,
V

Comment: Then call it an integration test.  I don't think we are going to get a better answer by arguing semantics.

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits would be that the test would be written in the same envirment the stored procedures written and executed, maintaned by a specialized databse developer outside the main application. 
There is no need for the application developer to be a master of programming a relational database nor for the database developer to master an modern application developing language. 
You now have test for every thing. Why not have them for the database written sql and executed outside any in house developed application.

If you are developing a multi tier application it makes sense to separate each part and test it separately.

Comment: I guess in my mind, databases were primarily meant for data, I try to keep logic out of the database. Even the majority of my stored procs are relatively logic free.

I see the point for DBA's, I'd like to keep them away from my unit tests :)

Comment: Yes they are, but they also have data manipulation capabilites. What we are usaually doing is providing bussiness logic in our software mixed with calls to the database, but what we really need is to pass some paramteres and expect a result in one call. When we do that, we need to automate tests.

Answer (score -1):

Try TST: http://tst.codeplex.com

Comment: This Unit Testing is not for MySql. The person is asking to develop a Unit Testing Framework for MySql.

Answer (score -4):

There shouldn't be enough logic in the database to make testing worthwhile.

Comment: Why not? A database is a powerful tool which in most cases sits unused to the full. Why not use it?

Comment: Computer science books often urge users to take full advantage of the database to do more so that the program can do less.  The database can often perform complex logic using such constructs as multiple joins, nested selects, `IN` clauses, and the like, much faster than a programmer's first implementation, more bug-free, and with much less programming work by the user.  (This isn't always the case; sometimes the DB is a bottleneck that careful algorithmic programming can overcome.)  In general, it's simply not true that there's not enough logic in the DB to make testing worthwhile.